# Transform a single object into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an object that consists in the number of occurrences for different words. It looks like this :

```
{
Word1 : 1,
Word2 : 1,
Word3 : 2,
Word4 : 3
}
```

I would like to have an array that looks like this :

```
[
{word:Word1, count:1},
{word:Word2, count:1},
{word:Word3, count:2},
{word:Word4, count:3},
]
```

I looked a bit around and found this code that loops through the object and get the values I want :

```
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
}
```

I tried to create an empty array and to use `push` to get the intended values in it, but I don't seem to get the hang of it. I feel like something along those lines should get me the result I want :

```
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    //Here is where the code should go, something like :
    myNewObject[i].word = key;
    myNewObject[i].count = p[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be `word4`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var obj = {
 Word1 : 1,
 Word2 : 1,
 Word3 : 2,
 Word4 : 3
}

var array = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => ({
  word: key,
  count: obj[key]
}));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` on the `Object.keys` for this:

```js
let o = {
  Word1: 1,
  Word2: 1,
  Word3: 2,
  Word4: 3
};

let arr = Object.keys(o).reduce((a, b) => a.concat({
  word: b,
  count: o[b]
}), []);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
const start = {
  Word1 : 1,
  Word2 : 1,
  Word3 : 2,
  Word4 : 3
};

const finish = Object.keys(start).map(k => { word: k, count: start[k] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should push an object for each key in the object:

```
var result = [];
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    result.push({
      word: key,
      count: p[key]
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate through each key in the object.
Use `map()` or `forEach()` to get the desired result.

```js
let o = {
  Word1: 1,
  Word2: 1,
  Word3: 2,
  Word4: 3
};

var result = [];

Object.keys(o).forEach(function(x){
  result.push({word: x, count : o[x]});
});

console.log("Result with forEach :" ,result);

var resultWithMap = Object.keys(o).map( x =>
  ({ word : x, count : o[x] }) );

console.log("Result with map :" , resultWithMap);
```